# Makefile: determine build if build target is amd64, so that I can adapt CFLAGS=-fPIC

Tags: x86-64, packaging, pic, deb, fpic

I am packaging a deb file and the configure script is not checking if -fPIC is needed. Thus builds on amd64 fails (as PIC is mandatory).

How can I determine in the Makefile or better in the debian/rules, if -fPIC is needed?

Comment: Is there some reason you want to *omit* `-fPIC` on some other ISAs?  That sounds weird.  `-fPIC` is normally only needed for shared libs, and those should be built with `-fPIC` everywhere, I think, even if some ISAs like maybe 32-bit x86 allow runtime fixups for non-position-independent code in ELF shared objects.  Are you disabling symbol interposition for i386 to gain sustained performance there at the cost of slower startup and not being able to share pages of the `.text` section?

Comment: I wanted to build PJSIP back then. 
And the build scripts did not account for the need of PIC.
So, I needed to prepare the env before compiling.
Here, the (unmainted) repo: https://github.com/dennisguse/pjsip

Comment: Oh, I re-read your question phrasing.  I earlier missed the part where config wasn't testing if `-fPIC` was needed.  (and/or the answers that only enable on x86-64 mislead me).  **For a library you should just always use `-fPIC`, even if it happens to work on i386 without it**.  (I'm not sure if that's likely but I think it's plausible. 
 And would explain how a Makefile existed that failed to use it.)    So you weren't intentionally trying to omit `-fPIC` in some cases.  I'm not familiar with https://www.pjsip.org/ but I assume it's just a normal library.

Comment: I think 2013 was too early for anyone to have their GCC configured with `-fPIE` as the default which would make position-independent code (but *without* assuming symbol interposition).  i386 is my best guess at a platform that could possibly work without `-fPIC`: addresses are 32-bit and anywhere in the machine code that uses an address embeds it as a single 32-bit immediate value. So relocations for fixing up addresses at dynamic-link time can be emitted, allowing non-position-independent code to be relocated to any possible 32-bit address (unlike x86-64 when non-PIC uses 32-bit absolute.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uname --hardware-platform` probably isn't what you want, since it may very well be different from the architecture of your installed libraries and executables (think an i386 kernel and runtime installed on x86_64 hardware), and also because `hardware-platform` will often end up being "`unknown`" under Linux.

A well-packaged deb should probably use `dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_ARCH` for this (example outputs: "`amd64`", "`i386`", "`armel`", etc), so that it gets properly overridden if someone wants to cross-compile.

Answer (score 0):

It is `uname --hardware-platform`. This returns `x86_64`:

```
ifeq ($(shell uname --hardware-platform), x86_64)
   CFLAGS += -fPIC
   CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
endif
```